# Text regeneration with Hugging Face and python

Tags: python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am currently working on a project to generate text content(large) based on provided input text contents. The program should take input text contents lets say news on a specific topic from different news websites and it will merge the inputs text keeping the information intact and generate a new text  output [length may be around 2000 words] which should have  all the input information. However output should not be same as input. I have used Hugging Face text summarization for this purpose but that doesn't fit here as I am not looking for summery which has few words, rather I want to recreate/rewrite  the input text contents differently.
Can this be achieved with Hugging Face, Python?

So far I  tried below two approach but it doesn't fit into my purpose well.

Summarization:::

from transformers import pipeline

```
# Open and read the article
f = open("sample.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
to_tokenize = f.read()

# Initialize the HuggingFace summarization pipeline
summarizer = pipeline("summarization") #"text-classification"
summarized = summarizer(to_tokenize, min_length=75, max_length=300)

# Print summarized text
print(summarized)
```

Text Generation:::

```
# Import libraries
from transformers import pipeline

# Specify the model
model = "gpt2"

# Specify the task
task = "text-generation"

# Instantiate pipeline 
generator = pipeline(model = model, task = task, max_new_tokens = 2000)
f = open("sample.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
to_tokenize = f.read()
# Specify input text
input_text = to_tokenize #"If you are interested in learing more about data science, I can teach you how to"

# Perform text generation and store the results
output = generator(input_text,max_length=500)

# Return the results
print(output[0]['generated_text'])
```

Comment: I apologize, I am beginner in python. I want to write a program which can do the following -
Inputs: It will take txt files as input which will contain information about a topic.
The inputs can be multiple txt files containing different information about the topic.
Action: It should be able to extract the information from all the txt input files, merge the informations from all files and provide a output.

Answer (score 0):

> Well, you can try using the Huggingface gpt3 EleutherAI/gpt-
> neo-1.3B
> model in the example below in Google colab
>
> You need to have your input text prompts in the workspace in an
> input
> text document of the format:

```
\file_name_for_responses_on_promptsblock1\
Prompt texts for file one, eg news papers 1
Prompt texts for file one, eg news papers 2, 3, ...
\file_name_for_responses_on_promptsblock2\
Prompt texts for file one, eg news papers 4
Prompt texts for file one, eg news papers 5, 6, ...
\file_name_for_responses_on_promptsblock3\
Prompt texts for file one, eg news papers 7
Prompt texts for file one, eg news papers 8, 9, ...
```

> You should upload this input_scripts.txt file in Google Colab
> workspace before running the code

```
# Install necessary libraries
!pip install transformers
!pip install zipfile

# Import required libraries
from transformers import pipeline
import os
import os
import zipfile
import re

# Set up Hugging Face GPT-3 model
generator_gpt3 = pipeline('text-generation', 
model='EleutherAI/gpt-neo-1.3B')

# Function to generate text based on a prompt
def generate_text(prompt):
    response = generator_gpt3(prompt, max_length=255, 
num_return_sequences=1)[0]['generated_text']
    return response.strip()

# Function to generate and save text files for prompts in a 
folder
def generate_and_save_texts(prompts, folder_name, 
output_folder):
    # Extract the filename from the folder name
    filename = folder_name.replace(" ", "_").lower()

    # Generate text for each prompt
    generated_texts = [generate_text(prompt) for prompt in 
prompts]

    # Concatenate the generated texts
    result_text = '\n'.join(generated_texts)

    # Save the result to a file using the extracted filename
    output_filename = os.path.join(output_folder, 
f"{filename}.txt")
    with open(output_filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as 
output_file:
        output_file.write(result_text)

    print(f"Generated {len(result_text.split())} words. Saved to 
{output_filename}")

# Read input prompts from the input text file
with open('/content/input_scripts.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()

# Create a folder to store output text files
output_folder = '/content/output_texts'
os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

# Process prompts and generate text files
folder_name = ""
prompts = []

for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("\\"):
        if folder_name and prompts:
            # Generate and save text files for the prompts in 
the current folder
            generate_and_save_texts(prompts, folder_name,     
output_folder)
        folder_name = line.strip().strip("\\")
        prompts = []
    elif line.strip():  # Ignore blank lines
        prompts.append(line.strip())

# Generate and save text files for the prompts in the last 
folder
if folder_name and prompts:
    generate_and_save_texts(prompts, folder_name, output_folder)

# Zip the output text files
zip_filename = '/content/output_folder.zip'
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'w') as zip_file:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(output_folder):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            zip_file.write(file_path, os.path.relpath(file_path, 
output_folder))

# Provide a link to download the zip file
zip_filename

# Move the zip file to /content folder for easy download
os.rename(zip_filename, '/content/output_folder.zip')

# Automatically download the zip file
from google.colab import files

files.download('/content/output_folder.zip')
```

> The code above sequentially finds full sentences (detected with an
> ending period (.)) as the prompt from the \text-blocks_names\ into
> the input of  the text Huggingface transformer generator function
> while concatenating the output for each sentence-prompt,
> typically,
> the generated text growth is roughly 10x the input (10:1
> output:input
> text ratio)

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the OpenAI version with the same functionality as my previous
> HuggingFace transformer solution, do not forget to supply your OpenAI
> API key

```
!pip install openai==0.28
!pip install zipfile

import openai
import os
import zipfile
import re

# Set your OpenAI API key
openai.api_key = 'Your_OpenAI_API_Key_Here'

# Function to generate text based on a prompt
def generate_text(prompt):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="text-davinci-002",  # Choose an appropriate engine
        prompt=prompt,
        max_tokens=250,  # Adjust as needed
        temperature=0.7,  # Adjust for diversity (higher values for more randomness)
    )
    return response.choices[0].text.strip()

# Function to generate and save text files for prompts in a folder
def generate_and_save_texts(prompts, folder_name, output_folder):
    # Extract the filename from the folder name
    filename = folder_name.replace(" ", "_").lower()

    # Generate text for each prompt
    generated_texts = [generate_text(prompt) for prompt in prompts]

    # Concatenate the generated texts
    result_text = '\n'.join(generated_texts)

    # Save the result to a file using the extracted filename
    output_filename = os.path.join(output_folder, f"{filename}.txt")
    with open(output_filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
        output_file.write(result_text)

    print(f"Generated {len(result_text.split())} words. Saved to {output_filename}")

# Read input prompts from the input text file
with open('/content/input_scripts.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()

# Create a folder to store output text files
output_folder = '/content/output_texts'
os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

# Process prompts and generate text files
folder_name = ""
prompts = []

for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("\\"):
        if folder_name and prompts:
            # Generate and save text files for the prompts in the current folder
            generate_and_save_texts(prompts, folder_name, output_folder)
        folder_name = line.strip().strip("\\")
        prompts = []
    elif line.strip():  # Ignore blank lines
        prompts.append(line.strip())

# Generate and save text files for the prompts in the last folder
if folder_name and prompts:
    generate_and_save_texts(prompts, folder_name, output_folder)

# Zip the output text files
zip_filename = '/content/output_folder.zip'
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'w') as zip_file:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(output_folder):
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            zip_file.write(file_path, os.path.relpath(file_path, output_folder))

# Provide a link to download the zip file
zip_filename

# Move the zip file to /content folder for easy download
os.rename(zip_filename, '/content/output_folder.zip')

# Automatically download the zip file
from google.colab import files
files.download('/content/output_folder.zip')
```